# Do 2 sodas in the fridge cool faster or slower than one soda in the fridge?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, freezing

If you put 1 room temperature soda in the fridge, will it take longer to chill than if you put 2 in the fridge, or will the 2 chill faster, or does not make a difference?  I guess, does the inherent heat of the pre chilled sodas hinder the chill rate of the others?

Comment: Did you make an experiment? Do you have a hypothesis of the outcome?

Comment: What would you expect if you put in 100 instead of 1?

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer is that one can will cool faster than two.

This can easily be seen by a thought experiment:

- Put in 1 can to get a standard cooling rate.
- Try it with 10 cans.
- Try it with 100 cans.
- Try it with 1000 cans.
- …

Unless the "fridge" is the back porch in Alaska in January, the number of cans will eventually be significant when compared to the total cooling capacity.

So even one additional can will slow the total cooling rate, though for a large capacity refrigerator the difference would be insignificant.

---

However, that answer is based on ideal theoretical situations, so **it isn't the only possible answer**.

In practice, real fridges don't maintain a perfectly constant temperature; they maintain a small temperature range.
When the air inside warms to above say 4°C, the compressor starts up and lowers the temperature of the cooling coils to sub-zero temperatures.
This continues until the sensor measures a suitably low temperature, say 3°, and then the compressor shuts off.
The air will continue to cool for a short while, down to say 2°.

Imagine putting a single can into a fridge that is at 3°.
There will be enough cold air available that the can will cool down before the air warms up to above 4°.

Now consider putting two cans into a fridge that is only slightly below 4°.
The compressor will start up almost right away, and the air will be chilled to 2°.
The two cans will now cool at a slightly faster rate in 2° air than the one can did in 3° air.

So yes, it *is* possible that two cans can cool faster than one can in the same refrigerator.

But in practical terms, the special circumstances will be rare, and the resulting difference would be very small and not useful anyway.

---

The real lesson here is to remember to put in twice as much beer as you think you'll need, and to do it the night before.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously, it depends on a lot of factors such as distance between the sodas, nature of cooling, cooling mechanism. In the most common and real case scenario :

Two soda will cool slowly as compared to a single soda.

---

This can be explained as:

Suppose the fridge can take up $100J$ energy in a minute. When you have only one soda, 100J is taken from it as a whole. But when you have two soda, you would expect that 50J heat would be taken from each soda. Hence cooling in the second case is slower.

---

Now you can argue that the process is not fully efficient and the positioning of the soda cans cause different rates of heating and so on.

But on a qualitative basis you can say that two soda cans cool slower than one soda can.

Comment: Because two pull enough heat from the inside to trigger the compressor, resulting in the interior of the fridge being pulled lower than it would have been by putting just one soda in the fridge...

Comment: @JonCuster I have updated my answer based on your comment. However, I still think that cooling two sodas will be more time taking.

Answer (score 0):

Most fridges have thermostats, so adding more warm objects will cause the cooling system to run longer to keep the air inside at the set temperature. While it is dependent on other factors it may normally take a slightly longer time to cool two sodas than it would one, but in general the difference is minor.